# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode when uploading txt file containing query to s3

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

Hi I have a query in this form :

```
data = {
    "pg_content": "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE CREDITCARDS.CC_TRANSACTION(\n    TRANSACTION_ID    DECIMAL   COMMENT 'Identifier.Values between 0 and 23162883'\n    ACCOUNT_NUMBER    VARCHAR   COMMENT 'Categorical Attribute with specific values as ACC2060,ACC1188,ACC1437,ACC5552,ACC98,ACC2240,ACC4096,ACC5555,ACC22,ACC4232'\n    TRANSACTION_AMOUNT    DECIMAL   COMMENT 'Values between -6125.96 and 600.00'\n    TRANSACTION_DATE    DATE   COMMENT 'Values between 2023-01-09 and 2023-06-16'\n    TRANSACTION_TYPE    VARCHAR   COMMENT 'Categorical Attribute with specific values as Purchase,Cash Advance,Void,Refund,Verification,Payment'\n    MERCHANT_NAME    VARCHAR   COMMENT 'Categorical Attribute with specific values as Merchant 250575,Merchant 265897,Merchant 54632,Merchant 100866,Merchant 749929,Merchant 250268,Merchant 486642,Merchant 27292,Merchant 250396,Merchant 108175',\n    PRIMARY KEY(TRANSACTION_ID),\n    FOREIGN KEY(ACCOUNT_NUMBER) REFERENCES CREDITCARDS.CREDIT_CARD_ACCOUNT(ACCOUNT_NUMBER)\n); "
}
```

I want to write this content to a txt file and upload it to s3 but during upload I am getting this error :

**[ERROR] AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode**

My code is :

```
local_file_name = 'local_file'
 metadata = {'_id':123 , 'name':'new'}
 text_file_path = '/tmp/' + str(local_file_name)  + '.csv'

    s3_client =  boto3.client('s3')
    with open(text_file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write(data.get('pg_content'))

    # Upload the text file to S3
    s3_client.upload_file(text_file_path, bucket_name, file_name)

    s3_client.put_object(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Key=file_name,
        Metadata=metadata
    )
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including the full backtrace it generates.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt this is whole code and on running you will get error straight away

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback?

Comment: This code does not call `.encode()`.  Therefore the error must happen inside some function call.  Don't make us guess where that is.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: Also, this is **certainly not** the full code.  `local_file_name` is an undefined variable.  `get_s3_client()` is an undefined function.  `metadata` is an undefined variable.  etc etc.

Comment: It's surely not the full code. For example, you are referencing `boto3` which isn't defined anywhere in your code. So I assume it lacks import statements, at least. Point is, it may not accurately represent the code causing issues, so it requires guessing, which is always wrong. The obvious formatting glitches which break Python code don't improve the quality either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So This turn out to be that Metadata should not be integer so by doing this:

metadata = {'_id': '123' , 'name':'new'}

solved my problem